# JAVA API For AWS Elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, java, amazon-elasticache

Yesterday I launched our first AWS Elasticache Redis instance, but haven't been able to use it yet via a JAVA API (Although the HTTP API seems quite straightforward to use)

I've tried first using the libraries available by including the following in the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.86</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I realized I must just need:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-elasticache</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.86</version>
    </dependency>
```

But there's also available:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticache-java-cluster-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I've found the Javadoc at:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/AmazonElastiCacheClient.html

But haven't able to really put/get data from the cache, as I haven't found any actual instructions on the libraries, could anyone please point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`aws-java-sdk-elasticache` is only for managing your Elasticache resources through the AWS API. Not for connecting and manipulating data inside the Elasticache server.

I think `elasticache-java-cluster-client` is only for Memcached clusters. Are you using Memcached or Redis?

If you are using Redis you should use a Java Redis client like [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis).

Comment: aha!!! I thought that the AWS API might have been for that purpose, but the documentation is not too clear for me. The instance is Redis based, so I'd give a try to the suggested Jedis, thanks!

Comment: Seems to work, at least it compiles, but I've just found out that I have to setup a "bridge like" NAT instance in AWS to test the cache from outside AWS (development process), so I guess there might be quite an overhead in using this AWS product. Any suggestions on such?

Comment: That's just the nature of ElastiCache. I run a local Redis server for local development, and only use ElastiCache when my code is running on AWS. You might want to check out RedisLabs to see if it is more to your liking.

Comment: Just downloaded a Redis Server (apt-get install redis-server), changed the default bind configuration and now I have a perfect development environment. Thanks a lot, Mark!

Comment: Looks like jedis doesn't support ssl with clustering.